# Excel Row/Column and number depending on another cell

Tags: excel, position, logic

I have a cell which has to have a relative content based on another cell. 
For example: if cell A1 has value 4, cell B1 has to take its content from cell "=B(4+2)". In the similar manner, cell C1 has the column value based on the content of another cell. So if the A2 cell value is 6, C1 should take its value from C+6=I column and row 1, something like "=(C+A2)1". Would be great being able to use relative column and relative row!

Is it possible? I was expecting a syntax similar to "=B(1+4)" but doesn't work.

Comment: Try learning about the INDIRECT function, I think it's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question.

> How to get "=B(4+2)"

```
=INDIRECT("B" & A1 + 2)
```

Your second question.

> How to get "=(C+A2)1"

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(C1)+A2,4),"1","") & 1)
```

The formula `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(C1),4),"1","")` is used to get the column letter. This gives you C. Here to get column `I` i.e. `C+6` I wrote `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(C1)+6,4),"1","")`. So the second formula turns out be `=INDIRECT(I & 1)`

Answer (score 1):

and an alternate form using [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) (not advised if using multiple times) is:

=OFFSET($B$2,A1,0,1,1)

and using [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) (preferred if you have lots to do) is:

```
=INDEX(B:B,2+A1)
```

For you other option about traversing columns you can use the exact same formula by changing up your offset direction or reference array in the index as follows:

```
=OFFSET($C$1,0,A2,1,1)
OR
=INDEX(1:1,COLUMN(C1)+A2)
```